# How is UTF-8 safe relative to ASCII chars

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

I was reading on Wikipedia, and came across the following:

```
"Since ASCII bytes do not occur when encoding non-ASCII code points into UTF-8, 
UTF-8 is safe to use within most programming and document languages that 
interpret certain ASCII characters in a special way, such as "/" in filenames, 
"\" in escape sequences, and "%" in printf."
```

What I can't understand is how this would be a problem, even if it happened. If the application processing the bytes supports utf-8 then that's a straightforward situation and there would be no problem since it'll know to interpret them in context of other predecessor/successor bytes. And if it doesn't, then it has no business dealing with it in the first place, and the fact that it might come across a combination of bits that's a format character like '\' is no more harm than already is processing it in first place.

Answer (score 4):

Take PHP for example. PHP has no native understanding of encodings (there are some asterisks and footnotes here, but let's say it doesn't). It looks for certain specific *bytes* in source code which mean something to it, and mostly just passes through anything else that doesn't have a specific meaning for it. E.g.:

```php
$foo = "bar $baz 42";
```

This triggers string interpolation; PHP will try to interpolate the variable `$baz` into this string. It does that by looking for the byte `0x24` (ASCII "$") and the next "non-word" byte in the string, which leads it to find the variable name `$baz` inside the string. Anything else in the string it just passes through as is.

You can do this on PHP:

```php
echo "意味分からない";
```

All PHP sees here is some binary blob which is of no particular interest to it. It does not support or understand those characters, but neither is it trying to do anything with them. It just passes the binary data through as is, and thereby happens to output the desired Japanese sentence.

Now, if we'd have written that sentence in some non-ASCII-safe encoding like, say, ISO-2022-JP-3, that would be:

```
1b24 4230 554c 234a 2c24 2b24 6924 4a24 241b 2842
```

You'll notice the `24` bytes in there. If you could produce a valid PHP file which contained these bytes between double quotes, PHP would try to interpret those `0x24` bytes as a `$` and try to interpolate variables there.

```bash
$ cat /tmp/foo.php 
<?php echo "B0UL#J,$+$i$J$$";
$ xxd /tmp/foo.php 
00000000: 3c3f 7068 7020 6563 686f 2022 1b24 4230  <?php echo ".$B0
00000010: 554c 234a 2c24 2b24 6924 4a24 241b 2842  UL#J,$+$i$J$$.(B
00000020: 223b 0a                                  ";.
$ php /tmp/foo.php 
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: B0UL in /tmp/foo.php on line 1
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: i in /tmp/foo.php on line 1
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: J in /tmp/foo.php on line 1
```

*That's* one example of a situation where UTF-8 compatibility with ASCII is important.

Comment: That's very interesting. It might be relevant to note that by definition, all bytes in a UTF-8 sequence encoding a Unicode character outside of the ASCII range (0-127) consist entirely of bytes greater than or equal to 128, so it's impossible that a stray 24 would turn up somewhere else in a UTF-8-encoded file.

Comment: Exactly, that's what makes UTF-8 "ASCII compatible".

Comment: ...Rereading the question, I see that this was already mentioned there :)

Comment: I understand the mechanics of how utf-8 is ascii-safe, but what I can't imagine is a context in which this can be not the case, i.e. an encoding that understands Unicode, Ascii included, but not Ascii-safe. Say utf-8 produces ascii-like bytes when encoding other non-ascii code points, then it's only natural that the processing decoding algorithm would know how to interpret those in perspective, not confuse them as distinct ASCIIs. If it produced ASCII octets, there gotta be some logic as to differentiate those and interpret them right.. .

Comment: @Learnerer As I tried to demonstrate, there are naïve systems which *do not decode anything.* They look for specific byte sequences, and ignore anything else. They're only aware of ASCII or ASCII-compatible encodings, which do not need to be "interpreted in perspective" at all. They're just bytes, and those bytes have been decided by the gods aeons ago, and you just need to look for the bytes which mean something to you and you can ignore anything else. Or so the mantra went for these systems.

Comment: @deceze Thx. But as I said in my question above, if a system doesn't deal with non-ascii, then we needn't worry about it misinterpreting parts of the encoding as asciis, since having them processing such text in the first place is then an error, i.e. why care about error occurring on top of error.                       My take:  that argument I read looks to me as if it's trying to promote a plus quality in utf-8, when it's really only a natural feature that's to be taken for granted in an encoding that can handle ascii - hence my confusion..!

Comment: @Learnerer UTF-8 being ASCII compatible allows such naïve systems to "support Unicode" without actually supporting Unicode. I.e., you don't need to revamp the entire system to make it entirely encoding aware, it merely needs to not do anything with bytes that don't concern it. Yes, that's not how things should be done in an ideal world, but without this compatibility we probably wouldn't have such widespread Unicode support as we do.

Comment: Thx. .. just one last thing: those utf-8-encoded objects you refered to would still contain the genuine (intentional) ascii chars as part of the unicode, so the fact that utf-8 does not produce those ascii bytes as part of other chars, doesn't prevent those chars from happening in the encoding, and the situation you demonstrated above would still possobly occur.. ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow…!? If you have a byte in UTF-8 which is interpreted as a "$", that's because you meant to type a "$" there. If you contrast that with the ISO-2022 example above, there are many "$" in there which are accidental. You didn't mean for those "$" to be there, but the program which expected ASCII saw those random bytes as "$". UTF-8 avoids that. A program expecting ASCII will only see a "$" in UTF-8 when you *meant* to put a "$" there.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, intentional ascii characters.. . However, I think i's clearer now.. Thanks.